# action isn't invoked at the first click

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i have a page with authentification which forword to my template page where there is menus.

```
  <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>pages/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>userOK</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>pages/template.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>userNOK</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>pages/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>    
  </navigation-rule>
```

my page template.xhtml

```
<h:form>
<p:menu type="plain" style="width:200;box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px black;top:-18;left:-40" >
    <p:submenu label="Dossier" id ="Dossier" >  
        <p:menuitem update=":contentform,:messages" value="Nouveau Dossier" action="#{choix.setPage('ajoutDossier')}" 
    ....
    ....
</h:form>

<h:form id="contentform" >
    <h:panelGroup  rendered="#{choix.page == 'ajoutDossier'}">
        <ui:include src="Dossier/ajoutDossier.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    ....
    ....
</h:form>
```

the problem is that action isn't invoked at the first click i have to click 2 time , and before i click many time and action isn't invoked, and sometimes juste p:submenu which are in the last position work

also when it was no forward just the page template.xhtml it's work !

Comment: I think you misunderstood the concept of templates in jsf.. a template is just a template, you would never navigate to a template.. in a template you specify where do you want template clients to insert content using the tag <ui:insert name="" />. then, you create a template client (a xhtml page that uses the template, and declares what to insert). you navigate to the template client.

Comment: what do you mean by template ?
for me the template is page with layout west, north, or center then i use `<ui:include src="Dossier/ajoutDossier.xhtml" />` and with the attribute rendered i dsiplay the page in some layout (center)

    `<h:panelGroup  rendered="#{choix.page == 'ajoutDossier'}">
        <ui:include src="Dossier/ajoutDossier.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>`
can i you give a best solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not taking advantage of JSF templates. Instead of using a template and several template clients you have everything in one page; and render stuff conditionally. Look this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/java-ee-16-articles/265-facelets-tutorial.html) or any other tutorial about jsf tempaltes.
Normally you would have a template, which has all the layout and content common to all pages; and uses the tag `<ui:insert name="title" >Default content</ui:insert>` as many times as you need (with different names). Then you create a template client, defining the template using

```
<ui:composition template="./../resources/templates/templateFile.xhtml">
```

And then use the tag `<ui:define name="nav2">` to set the content to include in the template.

Besides that, about the problem with navigation in your code: when you do a navigation you don't update content, because after a navigation the page is completely loaded (no ajax). So first of all you have to remove your update attribute; and also you have to set the "ajax" attribute of p:menuitem to false; because by default it's true. otherwise navigation will not take place.
the redirect attribute in the navigation rule is not required if you did things ok. It can work perfectly fine with a forward. The only problem with forward is that the browser URL will not change, because browser is not notified of the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution i have to add `<redirect />` after the `<to-view-id>` of page which have the problem, because i read that JSF uses internal FORWARD instead of REDIRECT to navigate to the success page and this why the URL will not get changed but i don't really undestand why ??

here is the code who work :

```
  <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>pages/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>userOK</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>pages/template.xhtml</to-view-id>
      <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>userNOK</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>pages/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>    
  </navigation-rule>
```

also to not loose css of redirect page i have to add this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: You should be using `<h:outputStylesheet>` for CSS.